# Rails Resque - Including module from rails lib in worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am trying to include a module into my resque worker but I keep getting this error -

```
failed: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `build_page' for RefreshEventCache:Class>
```

The worker - /app/worker/refresh_event_cache.rb

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../lib/locomotive/render.rb'
class RefreshEventCache
  include Resque::Plugins::UniqueJob
  include Locomotive::Render

  @queue = :events_queue  

  def self.perform(url)  
    build_page(url)
  end  
end
```

The Module  - /lib/locomotive/render.rb

```
module Locomotive
  module Render

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module InstanceMethods

      def build_page(full_path)
        Rails.logger.debug "BUILDING PAGE"
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Resque undefined method error in external module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130071/rails-resque-undefined-method-error-in-external-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add the extend ActiveSupport::Concern to the main module Locomotive like this:

```
module Locomotive
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module Render

    module InstanceMethods

      def build_page(full_path)
        Rails.logger.debug "BUILDING PAGE"
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

Just guessing,... Ive used the extension with single modules but this seems to be logical for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried this but still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean ?