# Rails Resque undefined method error in external module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, worker

I'm having trouble calling methods from an included module inside a resque worker.  In the example below, I keep getting undefined method errrors when I attempt to call the `say` method inside the worker (which is in the TestLib module).  I've reduced the code down to bare basics to illustrate the issue:

**Controller**
(/app/controllers/test_controller.rb)

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def testque
    Resque.enqueue( TestWorker, "HI" )
  end
end
```

**Library**
(/lib/test_lib.rb)

```
module TestLib
  def say( word )
    puts word
  end
end
```

**Worker**
(/workers/test_worker.rb)

```
require 'test_lib'

class TestWorker
  include TestLib

  @queue = :test_queue

  def self.perform( word )
    say( word ) #returns: undefined method 'say' for TestWorker:Class
    TestLib::say( word ) #returns: undefined method 'say' for TestLib::Module
  end
end
```

**Rakefile**
(resque.rake)

```
require "resque/tasks"
task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

I'm running resque using the following command: `rake environment resque:work QUEUE='*'`

Gems:
rails (3.0.4)
redis (2.2.2)
redis-namespace (1.0.3)
resque (1.19.0)

Server:
nginx/1.0.6

Anyone have any ideas as to what's going on there?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you include a module, its methods become instance methods. When you extend, they become class methods. You just need to change `include TestLib` to `extend TestLib` and it should work.

Comment: *headslap* I think I've been working in rails too much lately.  That did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: If you do this and it still doesn't work, restart your server